# Fubini theorem on integral with brownian motion

Tags: integration, expected-value, fubini-tonelli-theorems

Consider $X_t = \int_0^t \int_0^t B_s B_r ds dr$

Computing $E[X_t]$ yields swapping integrals: $$E[X_t] = \int_0^t \int_0^t E[B_s B_r] ds dr $$

Why am I allowed to do this using Fubini's thereom?
I do not quite get which requirements are met in detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $r<s$ we have $$E|B_r||B_s|\leq E|B_r|[|B_r|+|B_s-B_r|]$$ $$=r+E|B_r|E|B_s-B_r|$$ $$=r+\sqrt r E|X|+\sqrt {s-r} E|Y|$$ where $X,Y \sim N(0,1)$. [I have taken $X=\frac  1{\sqrt r} B_r$ and $Y=\frac  1{\sqrt {s-r}} B_{s-r}$]. Hence $E|B_r||B_s|$ is bounded and you can apply Fubini/Tonelli Theorem to finish.

Comment: What do you indicate by the double bar in the expectation. Do you want to stress the order?

Comment: The double bar for $Y$ was  a typo. I have corrected it.  @Alif

Comment: I still do not know what you mean by $E[..|| ..]?$

Comment: $| B_r||B_s-B_r|$ is the product of the absolute value of $B_r$ and the the absolute value of $B_s-B_r$. @Alif

Comment: Sorry. I did only see these two double bars but now I can see the whole picture. Thank you very much.

Comment: Since $E[|B_r| |B_s|] <\infty \Rightarrow \int E[|B_r| |B_s|] d(r,s) < \infty$

Comment: Do you refer to this part of fubini?

Comment: Yes, when a function on the product is integrable you can evaluate the integral in any order. @Alif

Comment: But in order to evaluate the integral  w.r.t. product measure, you have integrate iteratively. But this is the consequence of the theorem?

Comment: Once you insert absolute values you can interchange the integral using Tonelli's Theorem. @Alif

Comment: Ah I see. Thank you very much.

Comment: Why is $E|B_r||B_s|\le E|B_r|[|B_r|+|B_s-B_r|]$?