# Expectation of a squared Ito integral

Tags: stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion

I want to evaluate the following expectation:
$$
     \mathbb{E}\left[ \left(\int_0^T W_t^2 d W_t \right)^2\right],
$$
where $W_{t}$ is a Brownian motion. For now, I have
$$
\left(\int_{0}^{T}W^{2}_{t}\, d W_{t}\right)^2=\frac {1}{9}W^{6}_{T}+\left(\int_{0}^{T}W_{t}\, d t\right)^2-\frac {2}{3}W^{3}_{T}\int_{0}^{T}W_{t}\, d t.
$$
I think I can deal with the $\frac {1}{9}W^{6}_{T}$ part. There are two issues I don't know how to approach. One is that I don't know the variance of $\int_{0}^{T}W_{t}\, d t$. The other one is about how to compute the expectation of $\frac {2}{3}W^{3}_{T}\int_{0}^{T}W_{t}\, d t$.

Comment: For the variance-type term, write $\left(\int_0^T W_t dt\right)^2 = \int_0^T W_t dt \int_0^T W_sds = \int_0^T\int_0^T W_tW_sdtds$. Can you do this part now?

Comment: In fact, you need not even perform the expansion : the first term can be simplified because of the [Ito isometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/It%C3%B4_isometry).

Comment: @SarveshRavichandranIyer Yes, I can do the computation writing in this way, and it gives me $T^3/3$. I wonder how to compute the last product term, just to verify the Ito isometry.

Comment: I'm not fully sure about the other term just as yet. Once I'm sure I'll write an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\newcommand{E}{\mathbb E}$

For the variance-term, use $$
\left(\int_0^T W_t dt\right)^2 = \int_0^T \int_0^T W_tW_sdtds
$$
whence $$
\mathbb E\left(\int_0^T W_t dt\right)^2 = \int_0^T \int_0^T \mathbb E[W_tW_s]dtds = \int_0^T \int_0^T (t \wedge s) dtds
$$

Where the Fubini theorem for exchanging the expectation and double integral applies since $\int_0^T \int_0^T \mathbb E|W_tW_s|dtds < \infty$ (for that, see the argument [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4217795/fubini-theorem-on-integral-with-brownian-motion)).

For the other , imagine we had a function $f(t)$ in place of $W_t$. The resulting integral would look like $\frac 23 f(T)^3 \int_0^T f(t)dt$. Now, $f(T)^3$ is just a constant, therefore one can slip it inside and write $\frac 23 \int_0^T f(T)^3f(t)dt$. Since the integral of a Brownian motion evaluated at a sample point $\omega$ is just the integral of some continuous function, the same logic holds on an $\omega$-by-$\omega$ basis and therefore $$
\frac 23 W_T^3 \int_0^T W_tdt = \frac 23 \int_0^T W_T^3W_tdt
$$
whence $$
\mathbb E\left[\frac 23 W_T^3 \int_0^T W_tdt\right] = \frac 23 \mathbb E\left[\int_0^T W_T^3W_tdt\right] = \frac 23\int_0^T \E[W_T^3W_t]dt
$$
where we can exchange the expectation and integral using the Fubini theorem once again , because $\int_0^T \mathbb E|W_T^3W_t| dt<\infty$. To see this, use an argument very similar to the one earlier: $$
|W_T^3W_t| = |(W_t + (W_T- W_t))^3W_t| \\
\leq |W_t^4| + 3|W_t^3||W_T-W_t| +3|W_t^2||(W_T-W_t)^2| + |W_t||(W_T-W_t)^3|
$$

and the expectation of the RHS is some polynomial in $t$ , which is obviously integrable on $[0,T]$. Once this is done,  you can use the fact that $$
\E[W_T^3W_t] = \E[(W_t +(W_T-W_t))^3W_t] \\ = \E[W_t^4] + 3\E[W_t^3]\E[W_T-W_t] + 3\E[W_t^2]\E[(W_T-W_t)^2] + \E[W_t]\E[(W_T-W_t)^3]
$$

using the independence of increments. Using the usual formulas, this comes to $3t^2 + 3t(T-t)$, which you can integrate over $[0,T]$ and multiply by $\frac 23$ to get the value of that respective term.

Comment: Why are we not using Ito isometry and the fact that the fourth moment of $W_t$ is $3t^2$?
$$
\textstyle\mathbb E[(\int_0^tW_s^2\,dW_s)^2]=\mathbb E[\int_0^tW^4_s\,ds]=\int_0^t\mathbb E[W^4_s]\,ds=3\int_0^ts^2\,ds=t^3\,.
$$

Comment: @KurtG. Because I thought the exercise was to illustrate the Ito isometry for this example. That is, show using "other methods" that the Ito isometry is true for $X_t = W_t^2$. I would have used it, you can see the comment thread above, but the OP mentioned they had to "verify" the Ito isometry rather than use it.

Comment: Small typo: the final result seems to me like it should be $3t^2 + 3t(T-t)$.

Comment: @JoseAvilez Corrected, thanks.